# Firebase AdMob throws IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: android, firebase, admob, kotlin

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Superclass com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzg of com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdx is declared final (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdx' appears in /data/app/io.github.basixkor.scipnet-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes12.dex)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeh.zzeO(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzey.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

This is a stack trace thrown by calling a `AdRequest`. I tried clean, and rebuild but it still not working.

```
find<AdView>(R.id.adView).loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build())
```

This code is a kotlin code for load a ad.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

And this is a layout.
How do I solve this error?

Comment: please show your code ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Edited, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a version problem. Make sure you have the same version of `firebase-core` and `firebase-ads`.

Comment: oh god! that was it

Answer (score 0):

If adView is id of `AdView` in your activity_main.xml

Then you can use in this way :

```
private AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  //layout having AdView
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest.Builder builder =new AdRequest.Builder();
    builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
    AdRequest adRequest = builder.build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

Comment: can you post your layout.xml ?

Comment: @AbhisekAryan I posted :)

Comment: check your dependency may be you have version mismatch such as x-ad.jar is dependent jar of x-base.jar ,both are different version.